# CSS Border Overlapped By Child Element

Tags: css, border

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cnJ6q/

I can't just add the border to the child element, it needs to be added to the parent (.dc-slick) - Is there any way to fix this? Z-index does not seem to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it. 1) Child element takes the same size as not-transformed parent element. Then background you should cast on parent element

```
.dc-slick {

    border: 3px solid red;
    right: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 30px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 30px; 
    z-index: 10001; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: black;
}

.dc-slick-content {

    color:white;
    z-index:9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 15px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
}
```

2) You should scale child approximately in same way as parent.

```
.dc-slick {

border: 3px solid red;
    right: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 30px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 30px; 
    z-index: 10001; 
    margin-top: 0px;

}

.dc-slick-content {

    background: black;
    color:white;
    z-index:9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 28px 28px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 28px 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The child div will inherit its parent's z-index no matter what you use.

The problem here is mismatching border-radiuses. Use the same border radius on each element, otherwise you will get this overlap.

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 30px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 30px;
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/cnJ6q/3/).

Comment: The border radius can't be the same since the parent element is bigger (wider) than the child element. In your example, there is whitespace between the border and the black bg of the child.

Comment: Need some kind of function to figure out the right border radius size.

Comment: I found that using the the same border radius gave a white gap between parent and child.  After a little bit of fiddling, a border radius of 27px for the child element worked best.  No gap, and also no overlapping the parent's border.  Not sure if this is just a firefox thing, or whether the rule of thumb should always be parent-border-radius - parent-border-width

Comment: I think the question asks to find a way to add border to child alone seperately and not about the css border i guess. The problem here is this, Since the parent does not has a height and width attribute the parent always takes the size of the child that it has in it. So when you add a border to the child it inturn goes to the parent.. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the background color and the border on the same element, so move the `background: black` to `.dc-slick`

```
.dc-slick {
    background: black; 
}

.dc-slick-content {
   /*background: black;*/
   /*border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 15px;*/
   /*border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;*/
}
```

Updated JSFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/RxyRV/

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually possible.
To bring the child element behind the parent border,
make the child relatively (`position: relative`) (or absolutely (`position: absolute`) , if this is already used) positioned and give a negative `z-index`.

This also works with `border-image`s, where it is very useful if you want to achieve a partially obscuring border image effect:

```css
.container,
.inner {
  width:  200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.container {
  /* from @https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Border-image_generator */
  
  border-image: url("https://mdn.github.io/css-examples/tools/border-image-generator/border-image-1.png") 27 / 20px / 0px stretch;
  border-style: solid;
}

.inner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.inner-2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner inner-1">
    Test 1, child element above parent border.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner inner-2">
    Test 2, child element behind parent border.
  </div>
</div>
```

The downside to this technique is that the child element with negative `z-index` doesn't get JavaScript mouse/touch events. This is something I have to find out as I use this technique for a slider where these events are used.